# Why does my group by clause behave differently for similar data from the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 7 columns **(state(primary key), police_pers_str, total_cases, quarantined, deceased, injured, date(primary key))**. I want my query to display results of the last date added per state. Only one entry per state per day is allowed (hence, state and date as Primary keys). For example, I added 7 rows (for 7different states) on 2020-04-28 but added only 3 rows on 2020-04-30.

For example, if this is my table: (data in the table is irrelevant. please consider only first and last columns)

```
state1      20           15          15          15       15    2020-04-28  
state1      20           17          17          17       17    2020-04-30  
state2      25           20          20          20       20    2020-04-28  
state3      15           13          13          13       13    2020-04-28  
state4      15           13          13          13       13    2020-04-28  
state4      15           13          13          13       13    2020-04-30  
state5      15           13          13          13       13    2020-04-28  
state6      15           13          13          13       13    2020-04-28  
state7      15           13          13          13       13    2020-04-28  
state7      15           13          13          13       13    2020-04-30
```

Now, I want to display 7 rows where it selects all 3 from the 30th and the remaining 4 from the 28th.

This query works perfectly and displays the **state** and last date added: `select state, date from PolDATA group by state having date=max(date)`. So it correctly displays 4 states with the correct date and the remaining 3 with the correct date:

```
state1 2020-04-30  
state2 2020-04-28  
state3 2020-04-28  
state4 2020-04-30  
state5 2020-04-28  
state6 2020-04-28  
state7 2020-04-30
```

But I want to display all columns. Here's my query: `select * from PolDATA group by state having date=max(date)` but it displays only rows with all from the 28th, without any column of anything added on the 30th:

```
state2      25           20          20          20       20    2020-04-28  
state3      15           13          13          13       13    2020-04-28  
state5      15           13          13          13       13    2020-04-28  
state6      15           13          13          13       13    2020-04-28
```

How do I alter my query to make it display all columns by last added date (in this case, 2020-04-30)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One canonical way to handle this is to join your table to a subquery which finds the latest date for each state:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM PolDATA p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT state, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM PolDATA
    GROUP BY state
) p2
    ON p1.state = p2.state AND
       p1.date = p2.max_date;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER`, an analytic function, provides another option:

```
SELECT state, police_pers_str, total_cases, quarantined, deceased, injured, date
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM PolDATA
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. didn't realize this could be accomplished with a join. still a beginner to mysql. (: